# Scaling flexdashboard gauge in R

Tags: r, shiny, scaling, gauge, flexdashboard

I'm trying to use `flexdashboard::gauge`, but it is always the same size(doesn't scale) and I don't know how to change it's size. I know there is a way to do this for normal plots using `renderPlot` and setting for example `height`. Is there a way to do something similar with `renderGauge` ?

It's my code:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny    
---



```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
```


Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("n", label = "Number of bins:",
            choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20)
```



Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


### Gauge

```{r}
renderGauge({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    dane <- round(runif(1,0,100))
    df <- data.frame(Label = "IRR", Value = as.numeric(dane))
    gauge(dane, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', gaugeSectors(
  success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)
))
  })

```

### Chart A

```{r }
renderPlot({
  plot(1:10,1:10)
})
```


Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
renderPlot({
  plot(1:10,1:10)
})
```

### Chart C

```{r}
renderPlot({
  plot(1:10,1:10)
})
```
````

The rest of charts are to fill the place.
Do you know how to make this gauge bigger?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This might not be too hard after all. The real problem seems to lie in `justgage.css`, which **fixes the height to 160px**. You can override this by adding custom css, for example in the following way:

File `extra.css`:

```
.html-widget.gauge {
  height: 100%; /*or try sth like 320px instead of 100%, whatever you prefer*/
}

.html-widget.gauge svg {
  height: 100%; /*or try sth like 320px instead of 100%, whatever you prefer*/
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}
```

And then edit the **yaml header** of your document like below:

```
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    css: extra.css
runtime: shiny
---
```

This expects the file `extra.css` to be in the same directory as your main document.

Comment: An additional question: how to remove the border/shadow of the gauge box?

Comment: You can also add the CSS in the top block right after the YAML header in between two `<style>` tags if you do not want to create the `extra.css`. This is a great answer for scaling the gauges though, definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The current solution ALMOST worked for me. I had to use google chrome inspect (right click) to find the div class name of the gage. In my configuration the gage was called ...

So I added the following to my CSS script...

```
.chart-stage {
  height: 180px;
}
```