# Set the proportions of a gauge (from flexdashboard) plot in a RMD report

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, flexdashboard, gauge

I'm using `rmarkdown` to make a report containing some gauge charts from `flexdashboard`, the problem is that I can't change the proportion of the chart.

Here's a reproducible example of the code I wrote:

````
---
title: "Reproducible Example"
author: "Name"
date: "3/6/2020"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars,"model_car")
MazdaRX4 <- mtcars[1,]
```

## Cars Gauge

A gauge displays a numeric value on a meter that runs between specified minimum and maximum values.

```{r fig1, fig.height = 1}
flexdashboard::gauge(MazdaRX4$mpg, min = 0, max = 50, symbol = 'mpg')
```
````

But when I knit the report my chart looks like this:
[image]
Is there a way to set the proportion of this kind of chart?

thanks in advance to anybody who can help!

Comment: `21` is the first value of `MazdaRX4$mpg`. What do you expect to see ?

Comment: the value is ok, I'm trying to make the gauge bigger

Comment: Ah ok. Did you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876572/scaling-flexdashboard-gauge-in-r) ?